# Is it possible to record sound via the USB Camera Kit in objective c?

Tags: ios, usb, core-audio

I would like to build a straight forward app that can intercept the usb sound input via the ipod/ipad usb camera kit.  Is this possible and if so what area within Core Audio should I look at?

Thanks for your help and any help is helpful!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS automatically reroutes microphone input from suitable generic USB audio input devices using the camera connection kit to all iOS audio APIs.

Comment: Thanks @hotpaw2!  If you know of where to find the document stating this that would be helpful too.

Comment: Found good documentation in the book, Learning Core Audio.  They have an example of what I need.